# Bootstrap Button CSS For IE

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In IE I am having a little error coming up. When I click my button it does this:

[image]

Which is the right, the problem happens when I hover over approve or user manager:

[image]

This ugly box shows up and its really weird since it doesn't show up in Chrome. Here is my CSS:

```
 .dropdown-menu {
     margin-left: 55px;



}

.btn{
     background: none;
     border: none;
     font-size: 17.5px;
     font-weight:bold;      
     width: 120px;
     color: white;    


}

.btn:hover{
   background: none; 
   color: black;
   border: none;
}



.btn:after{
   background: none; 
   color: black;
   border: none;
}

.btn:active{
   background: none;
}

.btn:active:focus{
    background: none;
}

.btn.active:focus, .btn.active:focus, .btn.active:hover, .btn:active.focus, .btn:active:focus, .btn:active:hover, .open>.dropdown-toggle.btn.focus, .open>.dropdown-toggle.btn:focus, .open>.dropdown-toggle.btn:hover, .close>.dropdown-menu.btn:hover, .close>.dropdown-toggle.btn.focus, .close>.dropdown-toggle.btn:focus{
   background: none; 
   color: black;
   border: none;
   outline: none !important;
}

.dropdown{
    position: relative;
    top: -60px;
    left: 900px;
}
```

And my HTML:

```
    <div class="dropdown">
   <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
  Dropdown
 <span class="caret"></span>
 </button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
<li> @Html.ActionLink("Approve", "Approve", "Admin")</li>
<li>@Html.ActionLink("User Mananger", "UserManager", "Admin")</li>                                          
  </ul>
 </div>
```

Comment: What version(s) of IE? There are tons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you hover over "Approve" or "User Manager", right click it and click Inspect Element which will bring up the DOM Explorer.. that will show you the CSS for those elements which are `<li>`.. not `.btn` which is what the CSS that you posted is referencing...

I am pretty positive that something like this in your CSS should work:

```
li:hover {
    background-color: #000000
}
```

Same thing goes for focus

```
li:focus {
    background-color: #000000
}
```

Comment: sorry after I posted my post I saw @ketchupisred post and I didn't mean to post the same thing.. just didn't see that post before I posted.

Answer (score 2):

Your CSS is referencing the button which is not the issue. The issue is the `li` inside the `ul` right below it. 
Answer:
You don't have any CSS that address the background color (on hover) of your `li`.

Something like this should work:

```
li:hover { 
    background-color:#000000; 
}
```